# DiscardVirtualMemory and Memory Mapped files

Tags: windows, winapi, virtual-memory

Windows 8 added the [`PrefetchVirtualMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn781432(v=vs.85).aspx) which is a great help with avoiding hard page faults when reading a lot of sequential data with memory mapped files.

Windows 8.1/10 also added [`DiscardVirtualMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn781432(v=vs.85).aspx) which would be great as to avoid reading in pages that will be overwritten. However, when invoking `DiscardVirtualMemory` on a memory address owned by a Memory Mapping the thread hangs and the function call never completes.

Is `DiscardVirtualMemory` supported with Memory Mapped files. If so, does one need to do something special (i.e. undocumented) to make it work?

Comment: It doesn't hang for me, at least on Windows 10.0.10586